# detection and counting objects in images using matlab

Tags: matlab, object, image-processing, detection, counting

my project is to count White fly in an image using matlab, I'm new to image processing so I don't know where to start from , I searched for papers about the topic but I could't find anything useful , my question is to help me start from a point and if you can suggest some papers can help me , thanks .

Comment: This a good start, counting rice with [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-enhancement-and-analysis.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of research in this area, but not specific to Matlab. Try using google scholar to search for papers with "computer vision counting" or similar keywords.

Richard Szeliski also has a very good, free to download textbook on Computer Vision which could be helpful: http://szeliski.org/Book/. Topics like Feature Detection, Segmentation and Recognition might be useful, depending on your exact problem.

When you have an idea of what you want to do, have a look at Matlab's Computer Vision toolbox: http://au.mathworks.com/help/vision/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your interest Amie